# CSS Make div stay at bottom of page

Tags: css, html, position

I have designed a page in Fireworks then imported it to Dreamweaver in CSS slices. I want the last slice (indexr4c1) to stay at the bottom of the page when content in the middle slice (indexr3c2) overflows off the bottom of it, I don't know if this is possible the way I have done it...here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>index.gif</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="description" content="FW MX CSS Layer">
    <style type="text/css">
    #indexr1c1 {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:955px;
height:143px;
background-image:url(index_r1_c1.gif);
    }
    #indexr2c1 {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:143px;
width:955px;
height:56px;
background-image:url(index_r2_c1.gif);
    }

    #indexr3c1 {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:199px;
width:185px;
height:326px;
background-image:url(index_r3_c1.gif);
    }
    #indexr3c2 {
position:absolute;
left:185px;
top:199px;
width:608px;
height:326px;
background-image:url(index_r3_c2.gif);
    }
    #indexr3c3 {
position:absolute;
left:793px;
top:199px;
width:162px;
height:326px;
background-image:url(index_r3_c3.gif);
    }
    #indexr4c1 {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:525px;
width:955px;
height:75px;
background-image:url(index_r4_c1.gif);
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#ffffff" >
    <div id="indexr1c1"></div>
    <div id="indexr2c1"></div>
    <div id="indexr3c1"></div>
    <div id="indexr3c2"></div>
    <div id="indexr3c3"></div>
    <div id="indexr4c1"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks very, very much in advance for any replies :)

Comment: holy nightmare, you're using absolute positioning on everything..

Comment: possible to do what you want but the code needs a lot of change

Comment: @Mike came outta fireworks, messy messy

Comment: yes indeed,  definitely not the ideal code lol

Comment: Please don't do that to your questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of giving it a position from the top, set it to `position:fixed` and give it a *bottom* distance of `0`.

```
​#bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WAEMJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Set `<div style='position:absolute;'>` and give it coordinates at the bottom of the screen.  [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp) has good examples.

Comment: don't list w3schools as a good place for examples.. that place is an atrocity. http://w3fools.com